# How can i validate json elements relatively to each other?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a json
{
  "phone" : "333-444-55-66",
  "mobile" : "333-444-55-66"
}
. How can I validate phone and mobile relative? For example, json valid only if first tree number a equals.

{
  "phone" : "***333***-444-55-66",
  "mobile" : "***333***-444-55-66"
} is valid.

{
  "phone" : "***777***-444-55-66",
  "mobile" : "***555***-444-55-66"
} is not valid.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Express that, for a given property value, a property with the same name should exist using json schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691332/express-that-for-a-given-property-value-a-property-with-the-same-name-should-e)

Comment: You cannot do this. Sorry.